# tried to install compiz now nothing on desktop

Tags: 12.04, installation, compiz

I installed ubuntu 12.04 32bit and all seemed well except I wanted **compiz fusion** too. After installing all the components from the software library, nothing seemed to have changed so I went to the terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install fusion-icon`.

Installation began and then I got a whole lot of errors (didn't think to write them down :( ) And now I can't see anything but wallpaper on my desktop! Also pressing `Ctrl-alt-T` won't bring up a terminal neither will `alt-F2`. I can get to a command line using `ctrl-shift-F1` but don't really know what to do once i'm there to fix the problem.

Comment: Tried to uninstall it? You can also try `cat /var/log/apt/history.log`, maybe the errors are logged there?

Answer (score 0):

AMD graphics card?

Seems to be the problem if you have one. If so, make sure to use the right drivers (not the standard ones) and have everything up to date